# How to do dynamic infer at Dataset

Tags: dataset, jena, inference

I'm trying to make the SPARQL endpoint system by jena. 
This system used Model Class and had been a dynamic inference.

But It is necessary to use the Dataset Class instead of Model.
And I want to use GraphID in SPARQL.
I think do a dynamic inference is hard when do it.

To do dynamic infer using the Dataset, How would you implement?

Comment: [RDFS and OWL reasoning with Fuseki](http://answers.semanticweb.com/questions/9699/rdfs-and-owl-reasoning-with-fuseki) from answers.semanticweb.com may be of some help.

Comment: [Can I configure Jena Fuseki with inference and TDB?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10468940/1281433) is also relevant (although it doesn't have an answer).

Comment: Thank you for answer. It seems to be no choice but to somehow on the system.